# How can I set to a default UIBarButtonItem a custom action?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

I have the following storyboard scenario linked with a navigationController:

- Home -> First -> Second -> ... -> Sixth -> First

Can I set the UIBarButtonItem action for always go back to Home storyboard and not to Sixth storyboard?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create the UIBarButtonItem:

```
UIBarButtonItem* cancelButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Go Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelTapped)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButtonItem;
```

If you want to go to the first controller of the navigation:

```
- (void)cancelTapped {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi @carlos21, thanks for your answer.

I already tried this before. The solution partially works. When I create the custom "cancelButtonItem" I lose the default back image of the navigation controller. 

Any idea of how can I solve it?

Comment: @newsted Can you try creating another UIBarButtonItem in the cancelTapped event and assign it to the navigationItem?, the title would be empty. And the event of that new UIBarButtonItem would just a normal back: [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]

Comment: Thanks @carlos21. Finally I solved the problem applied the first answer you gave me and I added a back button similar to the default.

Answer (score 1):

The Navigation controller mechanism will create automatic back button.

You may try using custom bar button and code for moving from one controller to another controller.

custom bar button will help you solving the problem. The code for moving from one page to other is as follows

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nextView") as NextViewController
self.presentViewController(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```